# how to parse time using dateformat in android?

Tags: android, date-format

date format has this am_pm field but how can put conditions in an if statement?

```
if(time = "pm") {
*do this* }
```

something like that. Is that possible?

Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: You need to provide more info.

Comment: I want to make something where if it's "PM" my code should multiply the given number. If it's "AM" my code should add the given number.
example
if(time = "pm") {
 num = num * num; }
if else(time = "am") {
 num = num + num; }

something like that :D

Answer (score 2):

AM_PM_FIELD is a constant int. I assume you want to see if a time is AM or PM? Check out the SimpleDateFormat, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
I haven't tested the following code so don't quote me

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("a");
String amOrPm = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Hey aleph_null ur reply was good.... but i have a doubt, here Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance() will return current date & time only right???  
If i want to send my own date time Calendar.getInstance(myowntime)? is this right?

Comment: from the android docs: "Calendar's getInstance method returns a calendar whose locale is based on system settings and whose time fields have been initialized with the current date and time". To use a different time than the current, create an instance using Calendar.getInstance() and then set whatever time you want. To do so, use the setTime method, or one of the other methods that begin with "set".